# Flutter. Column mainAxisAlignment spaceBetween not working inside Row

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget, flutter-card, flutter-column

I am trying to make a screen like this:

[image]

For this I'm using ListView with custom item.
Here is my code of item:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Card(
          elevation: 5,
          color: Colors.greenAccent,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 65,
                      height: 65,
                      child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                          child: Image.asset(
                            "assets/images/temp.png",
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                          )),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 18),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: [
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: const [
                              Text(
                                "Test title",
                                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                    fontSize: 17,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "TestDescription",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Spacer(),
                          CustomButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

I need align title and description to top, and custom bottom at the bottom. For this I'm using Spacer() inside Column and I wrapped my Column with Expanded widget. But when I wrap my widget with Expanded I get error like this:

> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints
> are unbounded.
>
> When a column is in a parent that does not provide a finite height
> constraint, for example if it is in a vertical scrollable, it will try
> to shrink-wrap its children along the vertical axis. Setting a flex on
> a child (e.g. using Expanded) indicates that the child is to expand to
> fill the remaining space in the vertical direction. These two
> directives are mutually exclusive. If a parent is to shrink-wrap its
> child, the child cannot simultaneously expand to fit its parent.
>
> Consider setting mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min and using
> FlexFit.loose fits for the flexible children (using Flexible rather
> than Expanded). This will allow the flexible children to size
> themselves to less than the infinite remaining space they would
> otherwise be forced to take, and then will cause the RenderFlex to
> shrink-wrap the children rather than expanding to fit the maximum
> constraints provided by the parent.

When I remove Expanded() and Spacer() the error no. But I get wrong view. See at the picture:
[image]

Please, help me what I'm doing wrong(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [IntrinsicHeight](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html) as parent of `Row` to get the desire result with `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,`, then for `Rows`'s children can wrap with `Flexible` or `Exapnded` widget.

[image]

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Card(
        elevation: 5,
        color: Colors.greenAccent,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6)),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: IntrinsicHeight(
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  // or exapnded
                  // fit: FlexFit.tight,
                  flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 65,
                    width: 64,
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    child: Text("Image"),
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  fit: FlexFit.tight,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Text("Item 1"),
                          Text("Item 2"),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Text("Item b x"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  flex: 1,
                  // fit: FlexFit.tight,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.cyanAccent,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: const [
                        Text("lT"),
                        Text("lBsssssssssssss"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: IntrinsicHeight  class is relatively expensive, because it adds a speculative layout pass before the final layout phase. Avoid using it where possible. Instead you can wrap with sizedBox and provide fixed size